# $x,y \in G$, $o(x) = 2, o(y) = 2, o(xy) = k, k\geq 3$. Show that $D_k \cong \langle x,y\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I know that $D_k = \{1,r, \dots, r^{k-1}, s, sr, \dots, sr^{k-1} \}$
and that I can use $\phi: s^i r^j \mapsto x^i(xy)^j$. 
I don't know what can be found using this.

Comment: $D_k=\{1, r, \ldots, r^{k-1},s,sr,\ldots,sr^{k-1}$ isn't a definition of $D_k$ because it doesn't explain what the group operation is; how do $r^3$ and $sr^5$ multiply, for instance? Once you've fully specified the presentation of $D_k$ in terms of your $r$ and $s$, you either need to find an isomorphism in both directions, or show a homomorphism in one direction and show that they're of the same size (since this will automatically imply that it's 1-1 and onto).

Comment: Note that you only need to show that the homomorphism(s) hold on the relations, because it will follow automatically for all the group elements once you've shown that - why?

Comment: Oh right. So I have to add $r^k = s^2$ and $s r^k s = r^{-k}$ to the definition. I don't understand the next step. Could you explain it a little bit more, please?

Comment: James: do you understand what a homomorphism of groups is? This isn't the place for a basic course on group theory, I'm afraid. Perhaps you should try the math.SE chat? You could likely find good interactive help there.